# Slanted video in openCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to make a movie with openCV.  I can put all the images into the avi and it works great, except that the image is slanted at a big angle.  It looks like it has been smeared across the image.

The frames are perfectly square, so it cannot be a matter of getting the height and width confused.  The images are 24 bit.  The other thing that is weird is that it does not seem to be consistent when it happens.  sometimes it looks great, sometimes it is slanted.

Here is an image from the movie:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/63600049/MIP.avi

Here is the code:

PINVOKE Method

```
                IntPtr _ptr = CvInvoke.cvCreateVideoWriter(AVIFilename, CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 15, size, 1);

                int count = 0;
                for (int n = 1; n < Frames.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (Frames[n].Trim().Length > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Frames[n]);
                            IntPtr ptr = CvInvoke.cvLoadImage(file.FullName, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LOAD_IMAGE_TYPE.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LOAD_IMAGE_TYPE.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
                            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
                                throw new NullReferenceException(String.Format("Unable to load image from file \"{0}\".", file.FullName));

                            CvInvoke.cvWriteFrame(_ptr, ptr);
                            //VW.WriteFrame<Bgr, byte>(frame);
                            count++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                CvInvoke.cvReleaseVideoWriter(ref _ptr);
```

EMGU Version

```
 public static void CreateAVIVideoEMGU(string AVIFilename, string[] Frames)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Frames[0]);

        VideoWriter VW = null;

        VW = new VideoWriter(AVIFilename, CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 15, bitmap.Height, bitmap.Width, true);

        int count = 0;
        for (int n = 1; n < Frames.Length; n++)
        {
            if (Frames[n].Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                var frame = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>(ConvertBitmapTo24(new Bitmap ( Frames[n])));
                VW.WriteFrame<Bgr, byte>(frame);
                count++;
            }
        }

        VW.Dispose();
    }
```

The images are all 24 bit jpg of the same dimensions

Comment: What OpenCV version are you using, and what OS is this? (Win/Linux/Mac)

Comment: It is EMGU 2.3 64 bit version (c# wrapper of openCV 2.0).  I am using a windows 7 machine.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the "smeared" image?

Comment: Change the tag from OpenCV to EmguCV and add the C# tag as well.

Comment: I have played with the width specified in CreateVideoWriter.  It does not matter for the slant of the video.  The frames just get compressed.  It appears that the writeframe function is the one that is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain codecs will only accept width (and sometimes height) values that are a multiple of 2, 4, 8 or more. I am unaware of this restriction in the MJPG codec, but the issue you describe is similar to what happens when you use said codecs on images with widths that are not a multiple of the specified value. You might want to see if making the width into a multiple of 16 fixes the problem.

Comment: You get the award.  It has to be a multiple of 4.  Thanks!

Comment: i just tried the code below but an exception occurs:
captureOutput = new VideoWriter(@"test.avi", CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 1, 1024, 1024, true);
what du u think the reason? 


exception: 
{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'AVITest.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely an image stride/pitch issue. Make sure you support images where the number of allocated bytes per line may not be equal to the width times the size of a single pixel. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with EmguCV, but I would expect it would support this.

Comment: I ensured that the stride and pitch are correct, I made sure that the image is correct on the openCV side of the wrapper, and I made sure that all the frames are the same size throughout the movie.  Could it be a 64 bit problem?  I made sure that the image is passing through the wrapper into openCV correctly (the image saves correctly from the openCV side without traveling through the wrapper.)